# $x^4+y^4$ powerful for relatively prime $x,y$

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, diophantine-equations, powerful-numbers

I asked this question on the NMBRTHRY mailing list on
17 February 2014, but it remains unsolved as far as I know.

Recall that a "[powerful
number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerful_number)" is a positive integer whose prime factorizations
$m = \prod_i p_i^{e_i}$ has each exponent $e_i \geq 2$.
(Equivalently $-$ though generally of little use $-$ a positive integer is
powerful if and only if it can be written as $m^2 n^3$ for some integers $m,n$.)
Pondering [this
Mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151126) led me to ask:

> What's the smallest powerful number that can be written as $x^4+y^4$ with $\gcd(x,y) = 1$?

> In particular, is it $3088257489493360278725196965477359217 = 427511122^4 + 1322049209^4$?

The gcd condition is needed for the usual reason:
if $x^4+y^4$ is powerful then so is $(cx)^4+(cy)^4$,
but the converse fails, and indeed any number $m$ can be made
powerful by multiplying it by some $c^4$ (say $c=m$ itself);
we are not interested in examples such as $17^4 + 34^4 = 17^5$.

There are only about twice as many powerful numbers $m \leq x$
as there are squares [the actual ratio is
$A = \zeta(\frac32)/\zeta(3) = 2.17325+$,
and if I did this right then the count is given
more precisely by $A x^{1/2} - B x^{1/3} + o(x^{1/6})$, where
$B = -\zeta(\frac23)/\zeta(2) = 1.48795+$,
and the $o(x^{1/6})$ is actually $o(x^{1/12+\epsilon})$
under the Riemann Hypothesis; but this is all
tangential to the question at hand].

Thus, as with squares, we expect only finitely many examples of
coprime $x,y$ for which $x^5+y^5$ is powerful, but *do* expect
$x^4+y^4$ to be powerful for for an infinite though sparse set of
coprime pairs $(x,y)$.  True, Fermat showed that there are no solutions of
$x^4 + y^4 = z^2$; but there are integers $m$ for which the elliptic curve
$x^4 + y^4 = mz^2$ does have infinitely many rational points, and indeed
we can use such curves to find powerful $x^4 + y^4$: compute solutions of
$x^4 + y^4 = mz^2$ until finding one for which $z$ is divisible by
each prime factor of $m$.  For example, taking $m=17$ eventually yields
$$
427511122^4 + 1322049209^4 = 17 \cdot 426218494746902449^2
= 17^3 \, 73993169^2 \, 338837713^2.
$$
This is the smallest example I found, but this method needn't
find solutions of "$x^4 + y^4 = $ powerful" in order of
increasing size, and I don't see how to organize an exhaustive search
that could provably find the smallest example if it is not much smaller
than the solution above (for which $x^4 + y^4 \doteq 3 \cdot 10^{36}$).
For what it's worth, Google does not recognize it.

By the way, it's much easier to search for powerful values of $x^4 - y^4$
(again with $\gcd(x,y)=1$), because $x^4-y^4$ factors, and each of the factors
$x+y$, $x-y$ must be powerful except possibly for a stray power of $2$.
This means that trying all $(x,y)$ with $x+y \leq H$ takes time
proportional to $H$.  For instance, it took just over 6 hours of **gp**
computation to find that
$$
10113607^4 - 4319999^4 = 6 \cdot 41056761311940^2
= 2^5 \, 3^3 \, 5^2 \, 11^2 \, 23^2 \, 37^2 \, 47^2 \, 313^2 \, 4969^2
$$
is the only example with $x+y \leq 10^8$, even though
$x^4 - y^4$ is still quite large (just over $10^{28}$).
This example *is* known to Google, but only as a solution of $x^4-y^4=6z^2$,
with nothing about $6z^2$ being powerful, let alone about its being
the first such example.

Comment: Google still doesn't recognize your first solution, though it has indexed your question according to search for the title.

Comment: Is it known that working with powerful $m$ doesn't help? (you need not care about $z$ in this case).

Comment: You mean, try all powerful $m$ up to about $3 \cdot 10^{36}$?  Unfortunately there's too many of them (must be at least $10^{16}$ even when we require that each prime factor be $1 \bmod 8$).

Comment: No :-). I mean to to use the affine quartic model $x^4+1=m z^2$ with $m$ powerful.

Comment: So what search strategy are you proposing?  (There *is* a way to go at it with elliptic curves that might be barely feasible, which I'll note when I next edit the question to remove typos like "for for" etc.)

Comment: I am currently testing this without luck so far. Find birational map from $x^4+1=m z^2$ to a Weierstrass model without known point. Maple found such map over quadratic extension of Q. Find the generators over the extension, try to map small multiples to Q, clear the gcd, check. My pain is sage is slow for finding the generators. Of course homogenize first.

Comment: As I'll report, I did try the first few $m$ past $17$ for which the curve has rational points, and in each case the smallest example produced of powerful=$x^4+y^4$ was even larger.

Comment: This doesn't surprise me. Do you need to clear the gcd or you get coprime solutions for free?

Comment: I used squarefree $m$, not powerful $m$.  This gives coprimality for free but you then need to impose the condition that the numerator of $z$ has a factor of $m$, which is why (in this approach) the solutions tend to be large.

Comment: Well, in my approach with m=17^3 i got solution smaller than yours, but after clearing the gcd 17 remained to first power. This doesn't answer your question.

Comment: I suspect $x^4+1=17^5 z^2$ has rational points, but clearing the gcd after homogenizing won't give answer, is this true?

Comment: Um, the curves with $m=17$, $17^3$, $17^5$ are isomorphic (just write $z=17z_1$ or $17^2 z_2$ in $x^2+1=17z^2$), and thus give rise to exactly the same candidates...

Comment: [Of course I meant $x^4 + 1 = 17 z^2$, not $x^2 + 1 = 17 z^2$.]

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies so you checked already up to $10^{16}$? For small values one might use pari as follows:
    for(m=2,20000000,n=8*m+1;if(ispowerful(n),for(x=1,(n/2)^.25,for(y=1,(n-x^4)^.25,if(gcd(x,y)==1,if(n==x^4+y^4,print1(n,":",factor(n),":",x,"^4 + ",y,"^4",",")))))))

Comment: Yes I checked, but not that way: you don't want to wait for **gp** to
*count* to $10^{16}$, let alone *factor* every number of at most $16$ digits!
Much better to try all coprime $(x,y)$ of opposite parity with
$x<y$ and $x^4 + y^4 < 10^{16}$; that's only 40 million or so factorizations,
which take a few hours to try (and as expected find nothing).  
Still it's hopeless to reach $3 \cdot 10^{36}$ this way...
Now that it's a couple of months since I posted this question,
I should post a partial answer evaluating different strategies,
the best of which might make the computation barely feasible.

Comment: Are there coprime $x,y$ with $x^3+y^3$ $3$-powerful? $1735^2+2463^3=2^4.7^4.73^3$, $397^3+683^3=2^3.3^4.5.7^6$ has average power 3.69522..

Comment: maybe worth posting a pointer to https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~jb12407/ANTS-XV/papers/ANTS-XV_elkies-goel.pdf in case others encounter this question and wonder whether it's still open [even tho that is easily answered by googling the conjectured number]

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: This is not a complete solution but some partial results that may be helpful for a complete solution. Also note that this is my first contribution to Math Overflow so I hope I follow all guidelines and I would appreciate tolerance and feedback if I did something wrong.

I couldn't find any further progress on this problem on the internet (other than this thread). I believe I can reduce the search space to about $\approx 3.5*10^8$ cases.

Any powerful number can be written in the form $mz^2$ with $m|z$, so we are trying to solve $x^4 + y^4 = mz^2$. Since $m|z, x^4 + y^4 > m^3$, we have to understand what happens for all $m < N^{1/3} ~ 1.5 * 10^{12}$.
Now $m$ must obey the following conditions (this is how I reduce the search space):

- $m$ must be squarefree.
- $m$ must be odd. Since $gcd(x,y) = 1, x^4 + y^4$ is either $1$ or $2 \mod 16$, but a powerful number is clearly not $2 \mod 16$.
- every prime factor $p$ of $m$ must be $1 \mod 8$, since if $p$ divides $x^4 + y^4 $but not $x$ or $y$, then $(x/y)^4 \equiv -1 \mod p$, so $p \equiv 1 \mod 8$.
- $2m$ must be a congruent number. Indeed, suppose $(x,y,z)$ is a solution to $x^4 + y^4 = mz^2$. Let $u = -4x^2y^2/z^2$, and let $v = 4xy(x^4-y^4)/z^3$. Then $v^2 = u^3-4m^2u$, so the congruent number curve $E(2m)$ is a principal homogenous space for the quartic $x^4 + y^4 = mz^2$.

Therfore we need to check curves with those odd $m$ such that each prime factor of $m$ is congruent to $1 \mod 8$, such that $2m$ is a congruent number which is $2 \mod 16$.

It is also known that there are no relatively prime solutions to $x^4 + y^4 = m^3$ (By Proposition 14.6.6 of Cohen's Number Theory: Volume II: Analytic and Modern Tools).

The next possibility, is $x^4 + y^4 = 17^2 m^3$. This means, we only need to check $m$ up to $(N/17^2)^{1/3} \approx 2.2 * 10^{11}$, i.e., $2m$ up to $\approx 4.4* 10^{11}$. By Table 3 of [http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masfaw/congruent.pdf](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/%7Emasfaw/congruent.pdf) (which counts the number of congruent numbers which are $2 \mod 16$ up to $10^{12}$), there are $59536672 + 62455317 + 66579936 + 73445274 + 81759844 + 12294626 + 2110645 = 358182314$ curves to check.

Answer (score 0):

If coprime integers $x, y$ satisfy $x^4 + y^4 = A C^2$ with $C = A B$ then no prime 3 mod 4 divides the LHS, and that implies $A = a^2 + b^2$ and $B = c^2 + d^2$.

Also, if $x, y$ are coprime then $x^4 + y^4$ is odd or twice odd, so that $A$ and $B$ are also odd, and thus $x^4 + y^4$ is odd.

Furthermore, we can assume that $A$ is squarefree because any squared factor can be absorbed in $C^2$ and then in $B$, and $A$ being squarefree implies that $(a, b) = 1$.

One's first thought is simply to assume that $x^2 + i y^2 = (a + i b)^3 (c + i d)^2$ and search for integer solutions $x, y$ by looping through ranges of $a, b, c, d$.

Another possible search strategy is to consider the equation in the form

$x^4 + y^4 = (a (a^2 + b^2) B)^2 + (b (a^2 + b^2) B)^2$.

Given that $x, y$ are coprime, there must be integers $p, q, r, s$ with $(p, s) = (q, r) = 1$ and pairs $p, s$, $q, r$ of opposite parity, such that:

$x^2, y^2, a(a^2 + b^2) B, b(a^2 + b^2)B  = p q - r s, p r + q s, p q + r s, p r - q s$

So one could search over sets of $p, q, r, s$ where for each set the procedure would be as follows:

1. Determine $P, Q = p q + r s, p r - q s$ and $R, S = p q - r s, p r + q s$
2. Perform the following in parallel, and abort step in the event any test applies:

   - Denoting $T = (P, Q)$ if $(P/T)^2 + (Q/T)^2$ does not divide $T$
   - For small(ish) primes, e.g. $2, 3, 5$, if $2^{2\alpha+1}$ || R or S etc
   - odd part of |R| or |S| not = 1 mod 8, non-3-divisible part of |R| or |S| not = 1 mod 3, etc, i.e. quadratic residue checks
   - |R| or |S| not a perfect square
3. Log solution we have found!

Comment: In fact if $\gcd(x,y) = 1$ then every odd prime factor of $x^4 + y^4$
is congruent to $1 \bmod 8$, not just $1 \bmod 4$
(and if $x^4+y^4$ is powerful then it must be odd).
That does cut down the search space a bit $-$ a number of bits, even $-$ 
but still not nearly enough to make it feasible to provably find 
all examples with $x^4 + y^4 < 3 \cdot 10^{36}$.
It is, however, one ingredient of the closest thing I have to
a feasible strategy, which I may post as a partial answer to
my own question if nothing better appears here soon.

Comment: I beefed up my suggested method with a few (obvious) extra checks, and this involves calculations of only GCDs, quotients, and square roots (not prime factorisations for example). But, as you say, the search space is very large. So probably a more sophisticated approach is required.